# Is there an equivalent to SQL's IN clause in XQuery?

Tags: xquery

Is there anything like the SQL `IN` clause in XQuery? E.g., I want to do something like this:

```
where  $x/lotClosedYn in ('Y','N')
```

using `IN` keyword is giving an error, I am using saxon for XQuery processing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `=`. It works set-based, so `("Y", "A", "B", "C") = ("Y")` returns true.